# TensorFlow generate frozen pb model to use on Android

Tags: tensorflow

I have been trying to generate a frozen model using the method provides by the Object Detection API (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py) to use on Android's TF Detect, but I am getting the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Not a valid 
TensorFlow Graph serialization: NodeDef mentions attr 'T' not in 
Op<name=Where; signature=input:bool -> index:int64>; NodeDef:
```

So apparently the pb generation is not valid for Android. However, I did test this with a pb model Google provides (http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_android_export.zip) and it works on Android.

My question is, is there a particular way to generate pb models for Android?

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this issue  when i  use a quantized ssd_mobilenet_v1 model.

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I opened an issue on the official repo and I have received some comments, however none of them have worked; this is the issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2823

I'm still trying to solve the issue, if I manage to find a solution I'll post it.